# What is the official website for libavcodec?

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav

I would like to use `libavcodec` for a project, the problem is i don't understand where i'm supposed to get the official release, this library is so popular that i can't tell what is the official website.

for example there are 2 major projects like [libav](http://libav.org/) and [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) that are using it but i can't find the official source.

Where is this website ?

Comment: "[Libraries with this name are provided from both the FFmpeg project and the Libav project, but they are mutually incompatible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libavcodec)". So I think the answer depends on *which* libavcodec do you want to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official site is at [ffmpeg.org](https://ffmpeg.org/). You can get the source with git or by using a release tarball. Git is recommended as it will provide the most up-to-date code and is stable the vast majority of times (and fixes come quickly). The release tarballs were designed for distros who "need" a release. See the [FFmpeg download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for more details.