# What are the differences between FFmpeg and Libav?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, libavcodec, libav

According to the first comment for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442901/what-is-the-official-website-for-libavcodec), and i quote

> > "Libraries with this name are provided from both the FFmpeg project
> >     and the Libav project, but they are mutually incompatible". So I think
> >     the answer depends on which libavcodec do you want to use.
>
> by user [aland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/929437/aland) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libavcodec)

What are the differences that exist between this 2 projects ?

I'm interested in video and audio encoding to H/X264, Mp3 and AAC with Mp4/Mkv containers; but more importantly i would like to start with a reliable and up to date library with a permissive license and widely supported on as many platforms as possible.

Comment: @pst so you find easier to study the whole ffmpeg project, after that study the whole libav project and than making a decision ?

Comment: I said no such thing. However, this question, as presented, is not a good fit for SO. It is asking for a recommendation which is remarkably similar to "What are the differences between MySQL and PostgreSQL?"

Comment: [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-and-relation-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most visible differences between ffmpeg and the fork for general users are the different binary names (`ffmpeg`, `ffplay`, `ffprobe` vs `avconv`, `avprobe`, `avplay` etc). FFmpeg merges most commits from libav, but it's not as reciprocal, so libav does not have as many features. Therefore, ffmpeg can do most of what libav can, but libav can't always do everything ffmpeg can.